# Move contents of one set of fields to another set of fields

Tags: field-update

On my Opportunity object:

I have created six custom fields

- AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c
- AVSFQB__Quickbooks_Id__c
- AVSFQB__QuickBooks_ItemType__c
- Sample_Generate__c
- Sample_Quickbooks_ID__c
- Sample_QuickBooks_ItemType__c

I have also created a custom button Process_Sample_Sent

I would like to click the button and move the field contents:

- AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c  to  Sample_Generate__c
- AVSFQB__Quickbooks_Id__c  to  Sample_Quickbooks_ID__c
- AVSFQB__QuickBooks_ItemType__c  to Sample_QuickBooks_ItemType__c

On the custom button, I have selected:

- Display type - Detail Page Button
- Behavior - Execute JavaScript
- Content Source - OnClick JavaScript

  ```
  {!Opportunity.Sample_Generate__c} =     {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c} 
  {!Opportunity.Sample_Quickbooks_ID__c} = {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Quickbooks_Id__c} 
  {!Opportunity.Sample_QuickBooks_ItemType__c} = !Opportunity.AVSFQB__QuickBooks_ItemType__c}
  ```

This throws an "Unexpected token = " error

Here is my modified code that is throwing the same error.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity__c");
    record.Id = ("Opportunity__c.Id");
    record.{!Opportunity.Sample_Generate__c} = {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c};
var result = sforce.connection.update([record]);
// check the result here
window.location.reload();
```

Thank you Ardian,
Here is the code edited with your suggestion. It is throwing an "Unexpected Identifier" error

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity__c"); 
record.Id = ("Opportunity__c.Id"); 
record.Sample_Generate__c = {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c}; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([record]); 
// check the result here 
window.location.reload();
```

ARGH.. I didn't mention, AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c  is a PICKLIST and Sample_Generate__c is a TEXT field. I am trying to capture the PICKLIST value into the TEST field

Comment: Hi Stavros, and welcome to SFSE. Take a moment to look at [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64100/onclick-javascript-ajax-toolkit-custom-button-update-a-field/64103) and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: Stavros - please use [edit] to amend your question with the complete onclick Javascript code you are now using

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reference the field when setting them is `record.Field_Token__c`, not `record.{!ObjectToken.Field_Token__c}`.

Change:

```
record.{!Opportunity.Sample_Generate__c} = {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c};
```

to:

```
record.Sample_Generate__c = {!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c};
```